# Certification courses from a novice to professional

Tags: audit, career, certification

I would like to know the list of certification courses that I can start as a beginner and become proficient in the field of network security and from which website or institution can I take the training, appear for exam.

Also please let me know how to become a network auditor and how to obtain a job in this field?